# Angular2 on NodeJS not loading certain scripts

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

I am trying to get my Angular2 (rc4) application working on a Node server I have built but it seems to be failing with the following two errors:

```
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic//bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Now, I understand that these are packages that are included from within my systemjs.config.js file so I have checked this file and the location of the scripts from within my node_modules folder and this is all fine. The files are present there and there should be no reason why this is happening.

This has led me to think that there is an issue with my app.js NodeJS entry point file but I cannot seem to see a problem. I have included that file here:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));
app.use('/templates', express.static(__dirname + '/views/templates/'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


module.exports = app;
```

Can anyone see why these scripts are not being loaded? here is my index.html file for good measure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>

        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
        <script src="scripts/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script src="javascripts/systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.config({
                packages: {
                    javascripts: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }
                }
            });
            System.import('javascripts/app/main.js')
                    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
    </head>
    <!-- 3. Display the application -->
    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug //bundles should be /bundles
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9374